# Java - List create arraylist with wild card

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have created an arraylist like this syntax:

```
List<?> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

If I try to add a new Object or any object like String. It gives me compile error:

```
obj.add(new Object());

The method add(capture#1-of ?) in the type List<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
```

What are the objects I can add in `obj`?.

Comment: `List<?>` is a [list of unknown type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html), you can't add anything to it except of `null`.

Comment: You can't add anything with a `?`. Remember **PECS** [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: Also see [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java/) for an in-depth explanation to wildcards.

Comment: You want to avoid the duplication of `String`? Fine, use the diamond operator.

Answer (score 3):

You can add nothing but `null` in a `List` declared :

```
List<?> obj = ...
```

Otherwise you could break the type safety as this is legal :

```
List<?> anyList = ...;
List<Integer> integerList = ...;
anyList = integerList;
```

And this is also legal :

```
List<Integer> integerList = ...;
foo(integerList);

void foo(List<?> anyList) {
   ...  
}
```

If you could add anything in the `List<?>` such as a `String`, the list object referred by `integerList` would not contain not only `Integer` any longer.

To add any element in the `List`, just use the `Object` type :

```
List<Object> obj = ...
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  It is depressing sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

We can not add nothing to it(the sole exception is null) . See the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

> It isn't safe to add arbitrary objects to it however:
>
> `Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();`
>
> `c.add(new Object()); //Compile time error`
>
> Since we don't know what the element type of c stands for, we cannot
>   add objects to it. The add() method takes arguments of type E, the
>   element type of the collection. When the actual type parameter is ?,
>   it stands for some unknown type. Any parameter we pass to add would
>   have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don't know what
>   type that is, we cannot pass anything in. The sole exception is null,
>   which is a member of every type.

Answer (score 1):

`List<?>` means "It is a list, but I don't know what type of object is in the list".  Even though you have declared this as a `new List<Object>()`, it could be reassigned to a `new List<String>()` (for example) later.  And adding a `new Object()` to a `List<String>` is not a good idea.

In your case, you should declare it as a `List<Object>` rather than a `List<?>`.